# Misaligned GADM shapefiles and the NE dataset

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinate-system, natural-earth, gadm

I am very new to using GIS programs, so please excuse me if this is a trivial question.

I'm having the following problem:
When adding a GADM shapefile layer for Uganda onto the Natural Earth set of maps, the GADM Uganda map is shifted by about 11 km east compared to the NE map (a small difference but quite visible).

Following instructions in the answers to other people with similar problems I enabled "on-the-fly CRS", set both the layer CRS (in the GADM layer) and the project CRS to WGS84, but that did not change anything.  It looks like both the NE set and the GADM shapefiles have the same projection (WGS84), which is how it's specified in the metadata of both the GADM and NE layers. In this case of course setting the CRS to WGS84 shouldn't change anything. What could I look into next to try and fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem. The Natural Earth shapefiles are generalized to speed up rendering the whole world.

For me, the `_10m_` data has about 3 km offset, the `_110m_` even more.

The GADM dataset is very accurate. You can compare it to Openstreetmap background using the Opeenlayers plugin.

Comment: Indeed, OpenStreet aligns right off the bat. Thanks a lot!